# How to turn a List<Map<String, String>> with similar keys to a Map<String,List<String>>?

Tags: java, android, list, dictionary, multiple-value

I have the following List -

```java
private MiniProductModel selectedProduct;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_page);
        mPresenter = new ProductPagePresenter(this);
        mPresenter.initViews();
        mPresenter.initProductData();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Map<String, String>> attributesList = selectedProduct.getAttributesList(); //this is the list
```

So the raw value of what I am getting is the following -

```
[{value=Pink, key=Color}, {value=Yellow, key=Color}]
```

[image]

The final result that I want to achieve is a map containing one or more keys with each of them having a list of value Strings. For example - the product I have shown you here has 2 different colors, so I need the map to have one key named Color and a value list with multiple String values.

How can I turn my list to the wanted map?

edit -

here is my current result with Wards solution -

```
{value=[Sensitive Skin, Normal Skin, Combination Skin, Oily Skin, MEN], key=[Skin Type, Skin Type, Skin Type, Skin Type, Skin Type]}
```

The keys have been duplicated. why ?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to turn it into a map with a list of string values but got stuck figuring out how can I iterate for the entire list and compare the key with each key and add them to the correct list of the same key value @Ward

Comment: Your result shows a map with 2 keys: literal `"key"` and `"value"`, which is kinda weird

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue - combined with your answer before I have got my answer. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Stream (>= Java 8)

This can be done quite elegantly by using a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for the `List`, [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) to the entries of the `Map`s, and then collect using the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) collector:

```
// Note that Map.of/List.of require Java 9, but this is not part of the solution
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = List.of(
        Map.of("1", "a1", "2", "a2"),
        Map.of("1", "b1", "2", "b2")
);

final Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = listOfMaps.stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));

mapOfLists.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", k, v));
```

The output is

```
1 -> [a1, b1]
2 -> [a2, b2]
```

### For loop

If streams are not an option, you could use a plain old for loop, e.g.

```
final Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (!mapOfLists.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            mapOfLists.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        mapOfLists.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks really elegant! Though I am using Java right now so I will please need this solution translated to Java in order for me to use it

Comment: Uhm, this actually _is_ Java. This solution should work as of _Java 8_...

Comment: Actually, you would need at least Java 9 to use List.of and Map.of.

Comment: At first I though this is a Kotlin solution but it's nice to know that Java is advancing towards looking more elegant :) anyway, if you could give me a solution that can compile with Android (Java 8) that would solve my issue.

Comment: Not to speak for Ward, but the Java 9 elements was just to set the example up. Anything from 'final Map'... onwards is Java 8 compatible as far as I can see.

Comment: Added variant with a `for` loop (mostly automatically converted by _IntelliJ_

Comment: @NorthernSky, indeed

Comment: just tried that, this solution duplicates the key the same amount of times the value appears @Ward

Comment: @NorthernSky any suggestions as to whats missing?

Comment: That is hard to believe given that a Map does not allow duplicate keys?

Comment: So probably there is some misunderstanding here. Maybe you should clarify your problem more in detail

Comment: If you mean that the value (color) is duplicated the same amount of times each color appears, you can fix that by changing Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, Set<String>> and from toList() to toSet().

Comment: @Ward I have edited my main post so you can see the issue. NorthernSky what I mean is that the key (Color) is being duplicated for the amount of colors available. So for example I have the map with 2 keys and 2 values, how is that possible?

Comment: The issue is that you do not actually have Maps where, for instance, the key is Color and the value is Pink. Instead, you have a Map with one entry with a key named 'key' and a value named 'Color', and another entry with a key named 'value' and a value named 'Pink'. You would need to normalize this structure somehow.